# I am trying to run a python script but an attribute isn't recognised but I can import psutil

Tags: python, python-3.x, psutil

I get this error when I try to access an attribute from the psutil module in python3

```
2016-05-17 18:15:44,216 BOOT                 pyom| Logging system initialized.
2016-05-17 18:15:44,279 BOOT                 pyom| Entering Game Loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/duys/pyom/Rom24/pysrc/pyom.py", line 80, in <module>
    Pyom()
  File "/Users/duys/pyom/Rom24/pysrc/pyom.py", line 76, in Pyom
    game_loop(server)
  File "/Users/duys/pyom/Rom24/pysrc/comm.py", line 265, in game_loop
    start_snapshot = sys_utils.ResourceSnapshot()
  File "/Users/duys/pyom/Rom24/pysrc/sys_utils.py", line 29, in __init__
    proc_io = proc.io_counters()
AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'io_counters'
```

I don't understand because I can successfully import the module psutils and browsing through the psutil I find the method io_counters..

Even setting up a project on my PyCharm indicates that is has found io_counters, but when I try to run it I get that error?

Here is the snippet of code upon where it fails:

```
import psutil
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()


def sysTimeStamp(timeval):
    """
    Formats a raw time value into a formatted string in a standard format.

    :param timeval:
    :return:
    """
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(timeval).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


class ResourceSnapshot:
    """
    Creates a snapshot of system information as an object.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        sysmem = psutil.virtual_memory()
        proc = psutil.Process()
        proc_io = proc.io_counters()
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: What platform are you on? Your traceback strongly suggests OS X.

Comment: @Mart From the paths, it looks like OSX.

Comment: Yes I am on an OSX. I am assuming that is the biggest problem? Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of `Process.io_counters()`](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/index.html#psutil.Process.io_counters):

> OSX is not supported.
>   [...]
>   Availability: all platforms except OSX and Solaris

The attribute is not there because you are executing your script on OS X. See the [source code](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/bda8c65d7557904f895a5d795ced1c33508d6cc8/psutil/__init__.py#L692-L702), which only includes the method if the underlying platform-specific process class has that attribute. The [OS X implementation](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/psutil/_psosx.py) doesn't provide it, because the OS itself doesn't provide this information.

Comment: Thank you for that information. Is there a work around to this?

Comment: @UysofSpades: no, there isn't. The information is not available on OS X.